# Python - YouTube API v3 - How to get video ID only?

Tags: python, youtube-api

How can I get only video ID of video? As I know, I should use fields for that but I don't understand how do they work. My code:

```
service = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = api_key)
request = service.search().list(q = name, part='id',fields = *what should I type here*, maxResults = 1, type = 'video').execute()
```

"name" is search term variable. I get it from a file which contains list of names. By using this code I get information that I don't need. As I said, I need only video ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try your query here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it

I believe that the following query is the way in what you want to search and retrieve only the video id:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q={NAME}&type=video&fields=items%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

If for example {NAME} is psy, then this call returns the following data, from where you can retrieve the videoId of one of the items;

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "9bZkp7q19f0"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Ecw4O5KgvsU"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "o443b2rfFnY"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "WOyo7JD7hjo"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "QZmkU5Pg1sw"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

if you modify the example included in the python client library:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

you can do that in this way:

```
search_response = service.search().list(
  q="google",
  part="id",
  type="video",
  fields="items/id"
).execute()

videos = []

for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    videos.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how should I request from https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q={NAME}&type=video&fields=items%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY} using urllib2 pr something else? If I try to insert variable instead of actual name, I get an error. I use for loop to get names from file. 

Error: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code:

```
import requests
import json
payload = {'part': 'snippet', 'key': DEVELOPER_KEY, 'order':'viewCount', 'q': 'A R Rahman', 'maxResults': 1}
l = requests.Session().get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', params=payload)    
resp_dict = json.loads(l.content)
print resp_dict['items']
for i in resp_dict['items']:
   print "VideoId: ",i['id']['videoId']
```