# Video ID in Activity Feed

Tags: youtube-api

It would be very useful to return the video id with each activity. Only returning the video title and description seems strange. Am I just blind? Is there a way to get the video id with each activity item?

Here's the endpoint for the activity feed:

http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC3Ntz3-vGtr17V5JjUqiARA&maxResults=50&fields=items&_h=4&

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528958/python-youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-id-only

Comment: @beroe No, that's the search endpoint. Specifically, I would like to get the video id for each item in a user's activity feed - this endpoint: `/youtube/v3/activities`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the "contentDetails" in the value of the "part" attribute of your request -- that's where the videoID of the activity is contained. So, specifically, your request would hit the endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=UC3Ntz3-vGtr17V5JjUqiARA&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Perfect. "contentDetails" is correct. Thanks!