# How do I make a playlist with songs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

I have a list of song names that I'd like to make into a playlist with python, preferably youtube or spotify, I tried to do a script using youtubes api but I didn't find a way to get the video ID's of the songs to be able to use the api.

Comment: why don't you use some scrapping?

Comment: You could use a package like beautiful soup for scraping

Comment: I've got 1152 songs I need to add to the playlist, wouldn't scraping be kinda tedious or so?

Comment: Will this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528958/python-youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-id-only

Comment: maybe I'll try to get something to work out of it, thanks

Comment: Vishu,  you dont need to scrap everytime,  just use same session and do all stuff in once.  Use some hacks and do it,  rest is your choice.